# Wordpress floating plugin

Tags: widget, wordpress

Someon knows a plug-in to get a floating widget with a form/html like this website
  http://teambox.com/
  When you scroll down  a "form sign up floating bar" appears.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For this use a div, position fixed and top: 0px and place whatever you want inside. Have the div hidden and use something as the following to show after a certain height.

```
$(document).scroll(function (e) {

    if (document.body.scrollTop >= 300) {
       $('#your-div').fadeIn(200);
    } else {
      $('#your-div').fadeOut(200);
    }

});
```

No reason for a plugin.